# Server-side variables set by client call to server function persist? (No!)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I tried to use the [Revealing module pattern](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript) in apps javascript. I like the idea, but what it seems to have most acutely revealed is my ignorance of 1) javascript 2) apps scripts and 3) how they interact.

That pattern works fine when running a function in the editor (see test() below), but when run from a live webapp, it breaks down. I have the impression that values in the server-side javascript cannot be set using closures.

Whenever I run getEmail or setEmail in the editor, things work fine. If I call them from a webapp, the values set by setEmail do not remain set, so another call to the getEmail will retrieve the original values and not the values that were set by setEmail.

If the same javascript code were in the html page as a script, the settings would stick, I believe. (ok... will have to test that...).

The working code: 
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwrmi-b7J5Gqb_SDUUuiO-TTG31hQJVWtMLFvAPTPOb97qZaQw/exec

The code itself: https://script.google.com/d/1LNw54M-hMgafMfsnYBR0QzFlzXDhd9mFX4asghtqejJRC2Uh66zoFuAb/edit?usp=sharing

Core parts:

```
function doGet() {
  settings.setEmail("start email");
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('dialog')
            .evaluate()
            .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
}

var settings = (function () {
        var email = "blank";
        var getEmail= function () { return email}
        var setEmail= function (m) { email=m}

        return {
          getEmail: getEmail,
          setEmail: setEmail
        }
} ());

function getVal() { return settings.getEmail() }
function setVal(x) { settings.setEmail(x); return "set '" + x + "'"}

function test() {
  Logger.log(setVal("my email"));
  Logger.log(getVal());
}
```

Html code:

```
    <div id="output" >  <?= settings.getEmail()?> </div>
    <br>
    <input  id="input" size="20" type="string" />
    <input type="button" value="Set Value"  onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(serverSaid).setVal(document.getElementById('input').value);" />
    <input type="button" value="Get Value"  onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(serverSaid).getVal();" />

    <script>
    function serverSaid(reply) {
          var div = document.getElementById('output');
          var messages= div.innerHTML;
          div.innerHTML = messages +" | " + reply;
    }
    </script>
```

So, I tried doing the same thing client-side. It works as expected. Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="output" >  </div>
<br>
<input  id="input" size="20" type="string" />
<input type="button" value="Set Value"  onclick="serverSaid(setVal(document.getElementById('input').value));" />
<input type="button" value="Get Value"  onclick="serverSaid(getVal());" />

<script>
function serverSaid(reply) {
      var div = document.getElementById('output');
      var messages= div.innerHTML;
      div.innerHTML = messages +" | " + reply;
}

/// everything below has been moved over from server-side 
var settings = (function () {
        var email = "blank";
        var getEmail= function () { return email}
        var setEmail= function (m) { email=m}

        return {
          getEmail: getEmail,
          setEmail: setEmail
        }
} ());

function getVal() { return settings.getEmail() }
function setVal(x) { settings.setEmail(x); return "set '" + x + "'"}

</script>
```

Comment: *values in the server-side javascript cannot be set using closures.* -- what does that even mean?  The closure mechanism has pretty much nothing at all to do with client-server communication, at least not in any direct way.

Comment: Yep, that was my reaction too. But test works as a function, whereas the html app, which does the same thing as test but from the html page, does not. I can't find a reason for the difference. I am aware of course that I may be having a (hopefully brief) senior moment. I will add the (elegant!) HTML code in the OP.

Comment: Added the client-side version.

Comment: I think I have this all wrong. The problem doesn't have anything to do with closures (probably should change the title). **No server-side value can be set and remain that way between calls from the client** (I think)... This problem will have been one of those unfortunate learning experiences that we are supposed to be grateful for. But now apps scripts seems less powerful! I thought server-side functions were like using the functions on the page in the <script> block. All variables are reset between calls. New title: server-side variables always reset?

Comment: Yes I was looking into how that mechanism works, and that's what I was starting to think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstood some things. If I understand well your problem, you are trying to call some server side functions to set/get a value. But you actually don't store this value server side ! Differences you get is because of different contexts.

When you use the editor, the script is executed in this own context, meaning all instantiated objects/variables will stay as long as the script is executed (as long as you stay on the page).

But when you call these functions from client side, the server script will be executed once after a call and then its context will be destroyed as you "leave" (end of the execution of the function) the server.

So the value is actually changed, but the context where the value is changed is destroyed after the end of the execution. Finally, when you call the get function, you recreate a brand new context where the value is instantiated with its default value.

To handle this, you have to store the variable somewhere, into a database, for example.

Comment: Is this true for the UI interface as well? It seems more seamless than the html interface. The other solution is to move my settings object to the client-side javascript. If app properties are specific to users, I could just put everything there. (Not sure sure that will work, since I am executing as me...). Thanks!

Comment: @wgw Yes it is. Take a look at the HTML5 [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) in order to store these values.

Comment: My storage is really just setting a few persistent variables. It looks like all i have to do is just move some code to the client. Then when I call server-side functions, take the needed values with me. Thanks!

Comment: Pleased to help you :)

Comment: interesting answer, denotes a clear understanding of how all this works. very useful, thx & +1 too ;)